# How do I make a Dictionary return a method result?

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
//in SomeClass
pprivate Client _client = new Client();
public Dictionary<string, Channel> Channels = new Dictionary<string, Channel>();

public SomeClass()
{
    Channels.Add("main", _client.GetChannel("#channelName"));
    Channels.Add("secundary", _client.GetChannel("#secondChannelName"));
}

//in Client
public Channel GetChannel(string channelName)
{ //return a channel specific to this Client.
}
```

When I make `SomeClass()`, the dictionary gets filled with `Channel` objects from the current `_client.GetChannel()` returns. It saves the `Channel`s to the Dictionary, but I want it to add the -method- to the dictionary instead; and make every call to the Dictionary return whatever the current `_client.GetChannel()` returns the moment it's called.

For example, when `Channels["main"]` is called, I want it to call `Client.GetChannel("#channelName")` for me and return whatever it returns.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Call it? `Client.GetChannel(Channels[channelName])`

Comment: Wait, I see the sillyness in my reply. I can just make Client accessible; that works as a solution. Regardless, for the sake of learning then, would what I want be possible?

Comment: Are you looking for "how to write indexer method in C#"? Check out [indexers overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the channel name in the dictionary instead:

```
//in SomeClass
public Client Client = new Client();
public Dictionary<string, string> Channels = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public SomeClass()
{
    Channels.Add("main", "#channelName");
    Channels.Add("secundary", "#secondChannelName");
}

//in Client
public Channel GetChannel(string channelName)
{ //return a channel specific to this Client.
}
```

Then, in order to get the Channel object, call GetChannel:

```
string channelName;
Channels.tryGetValue("main", out channelName);
Channel thisChannel = Client.GetChannel(channelName);
```

If you're doing this from outside of SomeClass (because the client is private), you can expose a public method from SomeClass to do the same thing:

```
// to run it in a different class:
Channel thisChannel = someClassInstance.GetChannelObject("#main");

// in SomeClass:
public Channel GetChannelObject(string channelID) {
    string channelName;
    Channels.tryGetValue(channelID, out channelName);
    Channel thisChannel = Client.GetChannel(channelName);
    return(thisChannel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Func<Channel>> Channels
    = new Dictionary<string, Func<Channel>>();

public SomeClass()
{
    Channels.Add("main", () => _client.GetChannel("#channelName"));
    Channels.Add("secundary", () => _client.GetChannel("#secondChannelName"));
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
var main = Channels["main"]();
```

Or:

```
var main = Channels["main"].Invoke();
```